# Constant Maturity IV

Tags: options, implied-volatility

I want to analyze IV skew under various market conditions but its hard given various expirations. Would it make sense to create a constant maturity IV that say is 60 DTE? Has anyone done this and what are the limitations and things I should look out for? Additionally how do others calculate and compute it?

the way I am doing it is really to takes the left and right most closest to expiration. So if I want 60 DTE and the market has only 30DTE and 90 DTE traded options I compute those two IV curves and average them giving them 0.5 weight each. The weight changes as I progress closer.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by under various market conditions ? Across time for a given underlying or at a given date across many underlyings ?

Comment: Options only have one underlying...in my case equity index.

Answer (score 1):

You use a form of interpolation(start with linear) between the 30 day to maturity IV and the 90 to get the 60,

Answer (score 1):

You could check at the methodology for [VIX](https://www.cboe.com/micro/vix/vixwhite.pdf).
The VIX itself yields one number - but you might instead return a set of numbers for your skew analysis.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is fit a volatility surface for a given underlying. Once you have a volatility surface you can price an option for an arbitrary expiration and strike. There are numerous approaches to do this and the linear interpolation methods mentioned in the other examples are okay but be careful in the following situations where there is:

- a steep or curved forward curve
- you are pricing out of money options
- interpolating short term options or highly seasonal options since the surface can be complicated.
- finally watch that the implied forward Vols make sense (above 0 & have reasonable values). This is not guaranteed to be true with simple interpolation methods.

As an aside: Please do not trade options if you don't understand forward volatility